# Solving equation: $\cos x-\sin x (2\cos x-4)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following trigonometric equation

$$\cos x-\sin x (2\cos x-4)=0$$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), the equation reduces to $$t^4-12t^3-4t-1=0$$ where $t=\tan\frac x2$

Clearly, all the solutions are finite. But, the solution is not too [simple](http://goo.gl/HW2zby)